# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException Error

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've been stuck on this error for almost a day now and I don't understand why I am getting it.

The error:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Bind

Controller:

```
 var data = (from brand in db.Brand
             from division in db.Division
             from supplier in db.Supplier
             where brand.BrandID == division.DivisionID
             where product.SupplierID == supplier.SupplierID
             select new ModelGrid
             {
                   BrandID = brand.BrandID,
                   BrandName = brand.BrandName,
                   DivisionName = division.DivisionName,
                   CompanyName = supplier.CompanyName,
                   ContactName = supplier.ContactName,
                   Country = supplier.Country
             }).ToList();

  return View(data);
```

View:

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: ViewBag.count, autoSortAndPage: false);

 @grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("BrandID", "Brand ID", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("BrandName", "Brand Name", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("DivisionName", "Division Name", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("CompanyName", "Company Name", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("ContactName", "Contact Name", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("Country", "Country", canSort: true)
    )
)
```

and Model:

```
public class ModelGrid
{
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

From what I can find it seems you get this error when using anonymous types, however I thought I had avoided this. I am still learning at this point so any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works

```
grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: (int)ViewBag.count, autoSortAndPage: false);
```

I have a feeling its failing because ViewBag is a dynamic type and it doesn't know that Count is an int and Bind method expects an int for rowCount.

Comment: Thanks, this actually wasn't the problem but it showed me what the issue was. I wasn't passing the correct info as ViewBag.count, and I just couldnt see it probably cause of the amount of time ive had the problem. Anyway thanks again for helping me find the issue.